# how to get rid of colored grid on 100% cpu?

Tags: gui

Whenever there is 100% cpu usage, I see a colored grid on right top corner of the screen, which is on top, even if fullscreen video is being played.
This started happening after i fired update and upgrade commands.

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Is this on a model B+ Pi?

Comment: yes, on Model B+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model B+ displays a graphic at the top right of the screen if the power supply voltage is less than 4.65V.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=582098#p582098

The solution is to get a better power supply!